How to edit 'Domain Restricted Sharing' policy in GCP. Problem with setting policies in GCP as admin
I have created the Google workspace and I have domain with users.
I have account: adam@domain.com and I have with this account created the whole workspace and other accounts are under me.
There is account of my developer: xxx@domain.com and he has created a GCP on his account.
He tries to run the cloud run but cannot set: --allow-unauthenticated because he doesn't have the permission for domain restricted sharing.
When he enters the GCP-IAM-Organization Policies-Domain restricted sharing the Edit button is grey, cannot be edited and he sees this message:

The following permissions are required to edit organization policies: orgpolicy.policy.get, orgpolicy.policies.create, orgpolicy.policies.delete, and orgpolicy.policies.update.

The "Organization Policy Administrator" (roles/orgpolicy.policyAdmin) role is an example of a role that contains these permissions.
He also tried to change in GCP from his project to domain.com in IAM organization policies but this is what he sees:

You need additional access to the organization:  domain.com
This could be because you have insufficient permissions to access the resource, or because a Principal Access Boundary policy is blocking your access to the resource.
To request access, contact your organization administrator and provide them a copy of the following information:
Troubleshooting info:
  Principal: xxx@domain.com
  Resource: 666666666666

Missing permissions:
  orgpolicy.policy.get


So he told me to change it.
But when I went to the GCP from my 'admin' adam@domain.com account I didn't see his project, but I saw the organization domain.com in the projects tab.
So in IAM-Organization Polices I found Domain restricted sharing, but also for me the button Edit was grey.
It is very strange because I am the person that created the domain and administrator and I cannot change this thing in the organization level.
What should I do to:

Edit this policy about Domain restricted sharing?
Eventually give to my admin developer the role to change policies

